# Image processing algorithms

Tags: ds.algorithms

Is there any place, where description of formalized image processing algorithms can be found? Like creating hdr images, bluring images, etc.

Comment: You should consider asking this on Stack Overflow. (I'm not sure whether it is on-topic here or not, but I am sure you will get some useful answers over there.)

Comment: @Emil I already found one similar question there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435096/hdr-image-creating-algorithm . Not sure, if I should create one more.

Answer (score 1):

I know of two semi-related trends that may be of interest (so this would be an *extra* answer to your question, but not *the* answer).

First, some progress has been made recently on the problem known as "Affine Image Matching", given two images A and B, how much an affine transformation can make A look like B (see 10.1007/978-3-642-13509-5_2 which proves that Affine Image Matching is uniform-TC<sup>0</sup> complete).

Second, there has been studies of image transformations in the context of *weighted automata*.  A weighted automaton, which weights a word by an element of a semiring, describes fractal like images (intuitively, because of the loops of the automaton).  Nonetheless, actual algorithms have been invented to compress real-world pictures in weighted automata; a rational (weighted) transduction on such representations is then an image transformation.  See Chapter 11 of the Hanbook of Weighted Automata or the older Chapter 10, Volume 3 of the Hanbook of Formal Languages.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your particular topic of interest.  For foundations you can read some of the books dedicated to your topic.  For example, for HDR I recommend the HDRI book (by Reinhard et al.).  For deblurring I think there is a survey paper somewhere (sorry I can't post >1 link).

However, the field changes very quickly and the easiest and best way would be to follow the research.  (1) Go to http://kesen.realtimerendering.com/ and start reading some papers.  (2) Use Google Scholar to track the papers and very soon you'll be on top of the latest techniques in HDR, deblurring.  (3) Search for class lectures on your particular field of interest.  Very soon you'll find out who the experts are, and what the latest techniques are.  Go to their websites and look at their work.  I went through the whole exercise myself, from scratch, and it's actually quite fun.

Answer (score 0):

Found an article with some algos [here](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/programming/features/imageproc/). Also, there's a c++ implementation of hdr algo [here](http://qtpfsgui.sourceforge.net/about.php).